# Excel memory through the roof while deleting empty columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have a very strange problem with some Excel VBA code I created.

I won't get into the specifics (unless needed), but I have code which filters and copies data from one sheet to another.

On this second sheet it checks for empty columns and deletes them.

I have created this small macro to do the delete-part:

```
Public Sub deleteemptyrows()
    Dim C As Integer
    Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    C = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column
    Do Until C = 0
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(C)) = 1 Then
            Columns(C).Delete
        End If
        Debug.Print C
        C = C - 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Now this macro works perfectly and superfast (for the approx. 500 columns I'm checking every time) but the problem occurs when I call this macro in my VBA code (after the code copies the filtered data).

When it reaches the line `Columns(C).Delete` the memory of EXCEL.exe is going up to 6 GB in task manager, and it's running very, very slow column by column.

I have added the `Application.CutCopyMode = False` line because I thought it might have the copied data in it's memory, but that didn't help.

Any idea on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe try passing the worksheets name, alternatively, try deleting the column by the range function, rather than the column.delete. I generally use range, rather than column, you would need to convert the number into a letter in order to achieve this.

Comment: Are there formulas anywhere (even in another open workbook) which are affected by the deletions?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst you need to loop over the columns in the used range of the sheet - you don't need to delete them one-by-one. You can build a range - using `Union` - to create a non-contiguous range of columns with only headers and then delete them all in a single go. Using this technique in with disabling various properties of `Application` should give you an efficient method:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteColumnsEfficiently()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngEmptyColumns As Range
    Dim rngColumn As Range
    Dim wsf As WorksheetFunction
    Dim lngSetting As Long

    ' set a reference to worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ' set reference to WorksheetFunction
    Set wsf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    ' initialise range of empty columns
    Set rngEmptyColumns = Nothing

    ' set application settings to optimise ui change
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        lngSetting = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    ' loop columns in usedrange
    For Each rngColumn In ws.UsedRange.Columns
        ' check if only header populated
        If wsf.CountA(rngColumn) = 1 Then
            ' if just header - then add to range of columns
            If rngEmptyColumns Is Nothing Then
                Set rngEmptyColumns = rngColumn.Offset
            Else
                Set rngEmptyColumns = Application.Union(rngEmptyColumns, rngColumn)
            End If
        End If
    Next rngColumn

    ' delete columns with only header
    rngEmptyColumns.Delete

    ' reset application settings
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = lngSetting
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Robin. I had already added the xlCalculationManual in another part of the code but it didn't help for this deletecolumns-part.

Anyway: I tried changing the DeleteColumns-sub like you described, but I get the following error: 1004 - "Cannot use the command on overlapping selections"
It pops on the line "rngEmptyColumns.EntireColumn.Delete"

For reference, I should say that the columns that need to be deleted will still have a header row. They won't be completely blank, they just don't contain any values in the rows beneath.

Comment: Hi @flaviooooo - not sure about the error: `Cannot use the command on overlapping selections` - maybe you have merged cells or something. Anyway, I updated the answer to account for the header row by adding `Set rngEmptyColumns = ws.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0)` which will shift the range down by a row - assumes all your headers are in row 1. HTH.

Comment: Thanks again Robin... But unfortunately I can't get the code to work :-( I copied the data (and macro) to a new blank workbook, and now I get error 1004 "Application Defined or Object Defined error"... Maybe I can send you my workbook-test to have a look at what could be wrong?

Comment: If you (or anyone else) cares to have a look, I uploaded a testfile here: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/0d2a41f9c6cb4e321fac8c81a344b89420170415171041/238de0

Comment: @flaviooooo - seeing you source workbook was very useful. Hopefully my (completely) updated answer helps you out.

Comment: Glad to hear it - if you think its the correct answer then you can select the green tick mark to the left of the question to accept the answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run the sub routine by passing the sheet string, you may try the Robin's code as below...

Remember you are supposed to place this code on a Standard Module like Module1, Module2 etc. after inserting a New Module not on ThisWorkbook Module as you did in the sample workbook.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteColumnsEfficiently(ByVal strSheetName As String)

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngEmptyColumns As Range
    Dim rngColumn As Range
    Dim wsf As WorksheetFunction
    Dim lngSetting As Long

    ' set a reference to worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName)
    ' set reference to WorksheetFunction
    Set wsf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    ' initialise range of empty columns
    Set rngEmptyColumns = Nothing

    ' set application settings to optimise ui change
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        lngSetting = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    ' loop columns in usedrange
    For Each rngColumn In ws.UsedRange.Columns
    rngColumn.Select
    rngColumn.Offset.Select
        ' check if only header populated
        If wsf.CountA(rngColumn) = 1 Then
            ' if just header - then add to range of columns
            If rngEmptyColumns Is Nothing Then
                Set rngEmptyColumns = rngColumn
            Else
                Set rngEmptyColumns = Application.Union(rngEmptyColumns, rngColumn)
            End If
        End If
    Next rngColumn

    ' delete columns with only header
    If Not rngEmptyColumns Is Nothing Then
        rngEmptyColumns.Delete
    End If

    ' reset application settings
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = lngSetting
    End With

End Sub

Sub Test()

    DeleteColumnsEfficiently "Sheet1"

End Sub
```